# Google Earth Labels isn't Showing

Tags: google-earth

Google Earth's city/country labels isn't showing. How i can show it?

This is screenshot what i said: http://screencast.com/t/ZGMwMWNk

Comment: Also i upgraded my graphic card's driver. But it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked on the version I have installed (5.0.11733.9347 - from May 2009) and while there seem to be fewer labels visible they are there.

Have you cleared one of the sub options by mistake:

- borders

  - international borders
  - Country Names
  - Islands
  - Coastlines
  - 1st Level Admin Borders (States/Provinces)
  - 1st Level Admin Names (States/Provinces)
  - 2nd Level Admin Borders (Counties)
- Populated Places
- Alternative Place Names
- Labels

I can't think of anything else that would cause this behaviour.

Comment: Everythings is ok. But doesn't showing it. I changed graphic mode from direct x > open gl and open gl > direct x.. No way. :)